# Reading POSTed binary data from classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I need to read the binary data (a file that is uploaded) from a form that is posted to a classic asp page. I need to do this without using a component.

How do you read the binary data for that specific file? Note that there could be other non binary fields that need to be read as well.

(updated to clarify)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Request.BinaryRead` method:

```
byteSafeArray = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)
```

Comment: and how would you retrieve a specific input field?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated. See: http://www.asp101.com/articles/jacob/scriptupload.asp for a pure ASP solution.

Comment: @Derek: I think you'll have to read RFC2388 and construct a multipart/form-data parser - IIRC there's no other way to do it without a component: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad, the asp upload script did the trick. Much nicer solution than using a component too.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use clsupload. It is pure ASP and does not use any components.

Read here for everything you need to know about it:- [CLS UPLOAD](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=8525&lngWId=4)

I have used this in the past and it is still being used today on some of my old sites.